# Why is ajax always returning a fail?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

My ajax function is the following :

```
$.post({
    url: "login",
    data: {
        nomutilisateur: nomutilisateur,
        motdepasseutilisateur: motdepasseutilisateur
    }       
}).done(function() {
    console.log("Success");
}).fail(function() {
    console.log("Fail");
})
```

I always get the fail log; even tho my execute function inside my java class only returns "success".

Here is my execute method :

```
public String execute() {
    if (dao.validCredentials(nomutilisateur, motdepasseutilisateur)) {
        System.out.println("USER FOUND");
    }
    return "success";
}
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Check your console - do you get a 404?

Comment: No, and i have the log "USER FOUND" in my java console so i know the function is call'd and working

Comment: A good way to find out more about errors is to show them, instead of logging "fail" `request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ,errorText) {
  console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus , "Error: " + errorText);
});`

Comment: What do you see in the browser network tab?

Comment: @SLaks that is intriguing. I have a 404 error in my network tab related to my post

Comment: @KevinB thanks - forgot while copy paste...

Comment: the textstatus logged is :
Request failed: error

Comment: Press F12, go to console, if in firefox highlight Net error logging, refresh. Do you see any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the correct way :

```
@Action("/login")
@ParentPackage("json-default")
@Result(type = "json", params = { "includeProperties", "msg" })
public class Login extends ActionSupport {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String nomutilisateur;
private String motdepasseutilisateur;

private String msg;

@Autowired
private Dao dao;

public String execute() {
    if (dao.validCredentials(nomutilisateur, motdepasseutilisateur)) {
        System.out.println("USER FOUND");
    }
    msg = "success";
    return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: so, what change fixed it? using `msg`?

Comment: No, it's all about the Json stuff (parentpackage & result type) Not sure to fully understand why yet tho.